# Why is container exiting immediately after executing docker run command?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, port

I am running docker for the first time and my container is exiting immediately after docker run command. The `docker ps` is showing me an empty list. When I run `docker ps -a` I am getting the results of all the containers I pushed in Exited state.

I have tried using `-ti` command but the container is going in exit state. 
I am using following commands to run the file: `$ sudo docker build -t test_api3 .` and `$ sudo docker run -p  8080:3000 -ti test_api3` or (`$ sudo docker run -p  8080:3000 -d test_api3`)

Dockerfile

```
    FROM node:8
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    COPY package*.json ./
    RUN npm install
    COPY . .
    EXPOSE 3000
    CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "firstapp",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "first demo app",
      "main": "http-server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node http-server.js"
      },
      "keywords": [
        "S"
      ],
      "author": "test",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

http-server.js

```
    const http = require('http');

    const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
    const port = 3000;

    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      res.end('Hello World\n');
    });

    server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
      console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
    });
```

Comment: What do the logs say? You can run `docker logs $(docker ps -lq)` right after it's exited to get the logs of the last run container.

Comment: My issues is resolved but somehow I was unable to run the command. `docker logs` is giving me error that "docker logs" requires exactly 1 argument. I am unable to fetch logs for a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running ubuntu os and it works (Let me know your setup if it still cannot work). The only problem with the code is that you cannot use the address 127.0.0.1 and must use 0.0.0.0 in your http-server.js. For more explanation refer to the link below

https://forums.docker.com/t/network-param-for-connecting-to-127-0-0-1-in-container/2333

Comment: Thank you. It worked after changing the address. Just to understand the reason: it was not working because 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address which cannot be exposed to the other networks. So, we used 0.0.0.0 which identifies the local machine?

Comment: Yes that is correct. To go in-depth with docker networking you can go to their webpage it is really huge and comprehensive